# how the Converters work in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

how the Converters work in spring mvc? if i am sending a value as a String from the form which is of the type of some particular object, Does the string gets converted to that object type before it reaches to Controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converters work in very simple way - convert one value of  type to same value of different type.

> Conversion is the process where component data is transformed from
>   strings to Java objects and vice versa.
>
> Depending on whether the data is being sent from the client browser to
>   the application server, or from the server to the browser.
>
> For example a date field in a web form might represent a
>   java.util.Date object as a text string in the format pattern
>   yyyy/mm/dd. When a user edits a date field and submits the form, the
>   string must be converted back to the type that is required by the
>   application